# Java name entity recognition to return name and surname?

Tags: java, opennlp

i am new on using name entity recognition so i found a tutorial about it. I am using ner of [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/). This tutorial can identify full names (name,surname) and just names. Is it possible to make it return full names and how?

This is the code i have been working on so far

```
String[] sentences = {
        "Former first lady Nancy Reagan was taken to a " +
                "suburban Los Angeles " +
                "hospital as a precaution Sunday after a " +
        "fall at her home, an " +
        "aide said. ",
        "The 86-year-old Reagan will remain overnight for " +
                "observation at a hospital in Santa Monica, California, " +
                "said Joanne " +
                "Drake, chief of staff for the Reagan Foundation."};
NameFinderME finder = new NameFinderME(
        new TokenNameFinderModel(new FileInputStream("utilities/en-ner-person.bin"))
);
Tokenizer tokenizer = SimpleTokenizer.INSTANCE;
    for (int si = 0; si < sentences.length; si++) {
        Span[] tokenSpans = tokenizer.tokenizePos(sentences[si]);
        String[] tokens = Span.spansToStrings(tokenSpans, sentences[si]);
        Span[] names = finder.find(tokens);
        for (int ni = 0; ni < names.length; ni++) {
            Span startSpan = tokenSpans[names[ni].getStart()];
            int nameStart = startSpan.getStart();
            Span endSpan = tokenSpans[names[ni].getEnd() - 1];
            int nameEnd = endSpan.getEnd();
            String name = sentences[si].substring(nameStart, nameEnd);
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
```

and the result i get is 
    Nancy Reagan
    Reagan
    Joanne Drake
    Reagan

so how can i make it return only Nancy Reagan and Joanne Drake? Is it possible?

Comment: What's the links for "ner" and this tutorial that you mention?

Comment: its from a book named "Taming Text".

Comment: This one? http://www.manning.com/ingersoll/

Comment: yes,chapter 5. i am just using this book to have a better idea on ner with opennlp. I am creating a Q/A system as well but not as described in the book

Comment: you can use JAPE gate with Opennlp